# Saving an array in a database?

Tags: php, mysql

Here's my array:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "0002"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "0001"
}
```

It's passed form javascript to my php to save in a database.

Before saving to the database I:

```
$myArray = serialize($post['myArray']);
```

But in my database (mysql) I get this:

```
a:2:{i:0;s:4:"0002";i:1;s:4:"0001";}
```

Any ideas whats going wrong?

Also a var dump before database submission gives:

```
string(36) "a:2:{i:0;s:4:"0002";i:1;s:4:"0001";}"
```

Comment: Nothing is wrong. It is the result of `serialize()`. Use `unserialize()` to get your array back.

Comment: So, What's wrong with this, It is a serialized form of the array, you can get it back using unserialize()

Comment: I see, is this the best way to save arrays in a database?

Comment: you are getting correct result in your db, it is not wrong

Comment: @beans alternatively, you can also use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You serializing an array which result as formated string. When You retrive your data back from DB, You have to convert this string back into array using unserialize function.

http://cz.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php